# Prove $\vert e^x - 1 - x \vert \le x^2$ without derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, exponential-function

By comparison to the geometric series, prove that $\vert e^x - 1 - x \vert \le x^2$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\vert x \vert \le 1$.

---

I'd like to solve this without calculating any derivatives, but I'm seriously wondering how I can use geometric series here. The best way I could think of is a certain geometric series that is greater or equal to the left, but less than or equal to the right side ... But does such a series even exist?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of $\exp(x)$ ?

Comment: I just mean the natural exponential function, $e^x$. I've updated the question.

Comment: But what is your definition of $e^x$ ? is it $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ ? Or an other definition ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $|x|\leqslant1$, then\begin{align}\left|e^x-1-x\right|&=\left|\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots\right|\\&=|x|^2\left|\frac1{2!}+\frac{x}{3!}+\frac{x^2}{4!}+\cdots\right|\\&\leqslant|x|^2\left(\frac1{2!}+\frac1{3!}+\frac1{4!}\cdots\right)\\&\leqslant|x|^2\left(\frac12+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{2^3}+\cdots\right)\\&=|x|^2.\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

If $x \in[0,1]$, we get $$e^x -1 -x = \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!} \le \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^n}{2^{n-1}}= \frac{x^2}{2-x}\leq x^2$$

Credit and my gratitude goes to @orangeskid for pointing out how to correct my flaw.

Comment: Surely can't beat the constant $e-2=0.718\ldots$, so your lower $2$ looks odd too.